# Проблема с Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap.min, при нажатии на кнопку открытия меню на мобильных разрешениях, оно открывается и тут же закрывается, не давая перейти на ссылки. Своеобразный глич. В чем проблема? Как решить? Переходить на основной уже поздно, сетка портиться. У данной ситуации есть решение? JS подключен, ведь скрипт выполняется, но меню пропадает тут же.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Togglenavigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Main</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Matches</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Какое-то меню странное, почему не использовать готовое решение, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar?

Comment: Я пытался его использовать, но с min bootstrap'ом оно не работает

Comment: странно, ведь разницы то нету.. Может подключили неправильно?

Comment: очевидно вы не верно использовали готовое решение, делали что-то не так, тк, сжатая версия стилей по функционалу никак не отличается от несжатой